# multiple select query for the same tables with union

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, select

Using below query i want to find out the top number of students from each catagory(SC,ST,OBC,etc) on plus2percentage basis. eg i want top 3 students from SC catagory, top 2 from ST and Top3 from OBC. But i also want the top 5 from the open catagory, which include all catgory(SC,ST,OBC). but excluding the previous top 8 students from SC,ST,OBC Catagory.

So the final out output i want is like

top 3 students from SC Catagory. top 2 students from ST Catagory. top 3 students from OBC Catagory. top 5 student from(SC/ST/OBC/OPEN)but no one from the previous 8 students.

Total number of top Student= 13

WITH PRIMARY_CHOICE AS ( SELECT RollNo, ApplicantName, Catagory, Plus2Percentage,AppliedCourse, Major1 FROM (
            SELECT RollNo, ApplicantName, Catagory, Plus2Percentage, AppliedCourse,Major1,  row_number() over (partition by Catagory order by Plus2Percentage desc) as rn
            FROM RKMVApplicationFormData) as T 
            WHERE rn <= CASE WHEN Catagory='SC'  AND Major1='English' AND AppliedCourse='B.A'  AND Plus2Percentage >= 50  THEN 2
                           WHEN Catagory='ST'  AND Major1='English' AND AppliedCourse='B.A'  AND Plus2Percentage >= 60 THEN 2
                           WHEN Catagory='OBC'  AND Major1='English' AND AppliedCourse='B.A' AND Plus2Percentage >=50 THEn 1
                            ELSE 0
END ) 
SELECT RollNo, ApplicantName,  Catagory, Plus2Percentage,AppliedCourse,Major1  FROM PRIMARY_CHOICE UNION ALL
SELECT RollNo, ApplicantName,  Catagory, Plus2Percentage,AppliedCourse,Major1
FROM ( SELECT RollNo, ApplicantName, Catagory, Plus2Percentage,AppliedCourse,Major1,  row_number() over (order by Plus2Percentage desc) as rn
FROM RKMVApplicationFormData x 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
select 1 from primary_choice y 
where x.RollNo = y.RollNo ) ) AS T2 
WHERE rn<=2 AND Major1='English' AND AppliedCourse='B.A' and Plus2Percentage>=65  order by Plus2Percentage desc

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/53fbd/3)

Comment: TOP 4 without ORDER BY means "any 4".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what you are trying to do, how should the top 4 in each category be chosen for example, randomly?

```
WITH PRIMARY_CHOICE AS (
  SELECT ApplicantName, Category, Plus2Percentage
  FROM (
    SELECT ApplicantName, Category, Plus2Percentage
         , row_number() over (partition by Category
                              order by Plus2Percentage desc) as rn
    FROM RKMVApplicationFormData
  ) as T 
  WHERE rn <= CASE CATEGORY WHEN 'SC' THEN 25
                            WHEN 'ST' THEN 30
                            WHEN 'OBC' THEn 15
                            ELSE 0
              END
)
SELECT ApplicantName, Category, Plus2Percentage
FROM PRIMARY_CHOICE
UNION ALL
SELECT ApplicantName, Category, Plus2Percentage
FROM (
    SELECT ApplicantName, Category, Plus2Percentage
         , row_number() over (order by Plus2Percentage desc) as rn
    FROM RKMVApplicationFormData x
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        select 1 from primary_choice y
        where x.ApplicantName = y.ApplicantName
    )
) AS T2
WHERE rn <= 30;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30455/discussion-on-answer-by-lennart-multiple-select-query-for-the-same-tables-with-u).

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get the `TOP N` per category is using the `CROSS APPLY`

```
WITH Cat AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT Category
  FROM   RKMVApplicationFormData
), CatTop AS (
  SELECT t.id, t.ApplicantName, t.Category, t.Plus2Percentage
  FROM   Cat c
         CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 4
                             r.id, r.ApplicantName, r.Category, r.Plus2Percentage
                      FROM   RKMVApplicationFormData r
                      WHERE  r.Category = c.Category
                      ORDER BY r.Plus2Percentage Desc) t
  WHERE  c.Category IN ('SC', 'ST', 'OBC')
)
SELECT ApplicantName, Category, Plus2Percentage
FROM   CatTop
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 4
       ApplicantName, Category, Plus2Percentage
FROM   RKMVApplicationFormData r
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   CatTop c
                   WHERE  c.ID = r.ID)
ORDER BY Plus2Percentage DESC
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6990d/11)